# Constructing a list of strings following a statistical breakdown

Tags: c#

I'm building a function that will construct a list of strings by using a statistical breakdown provided as an argument. I'm looking for a more elegant and precise way to accomplish this. Here is a working example of what I have so far. This is working currently for simple cases, but I anticipate more complex cases causing issue (math rounding, etc.)

```
    public static void StatisticalList()
    {
        List<string> statisticalList = new List<string>();
        int totalCount = 500;

        // end goal is 30% of our result list has the value "1"
        List<string> entry1 = new List<string>() { "30", "1" };

        // end goal is 40% of our result list has the value "2"
        List<string> entry2 = new List<string>() { "40", "2" };

        // end goal is 30% of our result list has the value "3"
        List<string> entry3 = new List<string>() { "30", "3" };
        List<List<string>> container = new List<List<string>>(){entry1, entry2, entry3};


        foreach(List<string> entry in container)
        {
            double doub = Convert.ToDouble(entry[0]);
            double percentage = doub / 100;
            double numberOfElements = (double) percentage * totalCount;
            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfElements; i++)
            {
                statisticalList.Add(entry[1]);
            }
        }

        foreach (string i in statisticalList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why are you using a `List<string>` if you expect them to all be convertible to doubles? Shouldn't you use a `List<double>` instead?

Comment: @Rufus L input is captured through a text file, so the values will originally be read as strings and then converted.

Comment: If you have a text file they are comma separated so just read a line.  double[] pair = inputline.Split(new char[] {','}).Select(x => double.Parse(x)).  KeyPairValue<double, double> keyPair = new KeyPairValue<double, double>(pair[0], pair[1]);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things I would do to make this "more elegant". First, I would create a class to represent a rule, which is a "Goal Percent" and a "Value":

```
public class StatisticalRule
{
    public double PercentGoal { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }
}
```

Then, I would create a method that takes in a list of these rules, along with a desired list size, and returns a list populated with the values. I've added some logic to your code to adjust the percentage of each item in case the total is less than or greater than 100 percent (another option would be to just throw an exception if the totals don't add up to 100).

For example, if someone added 3 items where one was 60%, one was 50%, and another was 40%, we have to adjust those amounts (we can't fill 150%). So what I've done is determine the total amount we need to adjust (-50 in this example), and then, for each item, calculate what percent of the total that item's PercentGoal represents, apply it to the adjustment amount, and apply that to the rule's percentGoal (so in this example, 60% = 40%, 50% = 33%, and 40% = 27%), and then populate the list with these adjusted percentages.

I also use `Enumerable.Repeat` to add items to the list, which is a little more elegant than the loop construct.

```
public static List<double> GetStatisticalList(List<StatisticalRule> rules, int totalCount)
{
    List<double> statisticalList = new List<double>();

    // Capture any difference between our total percentages and 100 percent
    var totalPct = rules.Sum(r => r.PercentGoal);
    var pctDiff = 100 - totalPct;

    foreach (var rule in rules)
    {
        // Calculate the percentage of the total this value represents
        var pctOfTotal = rule.PercentGoal / totalPct * 100;

        // Calculate the amount we need to adjust this 
        // percentage by so the totals equal 100
        var pctAdjustment = pctDiff * pctOfTotal / 100;

        // Determine the number of items to add by adding our adjustment to 
        // our percentage goal and applying that percentage to the totalCount
        var numItems = (int) ((rule.PercentGoal + pctAdjustment) / 100 * totalCount);

        // Add the adjusted amount of this value to our list
        statisticalList.AddRange(Enumerable.Repeat(rule.Value, numItems));
    }

    return statisticalList;
}
```

Notice I'm returning a list of `double` instead of `string`. The method itself should work directly with the data type it expects when possible, and leave it to the caller to do any conversions. This makes for cleaner, more intentional code, and creates fewer assumptions.

To use this code with your example above, you would do something like this:

```
static void Main()
{
    // Create our rules
    var statRules = new List<StatisticalRule>
    {
        new StatisticalRule {PercentGoal = 30, Value = 1},
        new StatisticalRule {PercentGoal = 40, Value = 2},
        new StatisticalRule {PercentGoal = 30, Value = 3},
    };

    // Get our 500 item stat list with rules applied
    var statList = GetStatisticalList(statRules, 500);

    // Display the statistics
    Console.WriteLine($"Our statistics list contains {statList.Count} items:");
    foreach (var uniqueValue in statList.Distinct())
    {
        var valueCount = statList.Count(i => i == uniqueValue);

        Console.WriteLine(" - Value: {0}, Count: {1}, Percent of Total: {2}%", 
            uniqueValue, valueCount, (double)valueCount / statList.Count * 100);
    }

    Console.Write("\nDone!\nPress any key to continue...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

**Output**

[image]